# How to move the only file in every subdirectory to outside and change the name to the directory name?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have a large number of directories, each containing a file. The structure looks like this:

```
.
├── 1.apple
│   └── foo.txt
├── 10.banana
│   └── foo.txt
├── 101.orange
│   └── foo.txt
├── <number>.<different strings>
│   └── <same strings>
```

I want to move these single files one level up, rename them to reflect the name of the subdirectory where they currently reside, and remove the subdirectory afterwards. The result should look like this:

```
.
├── 1.apple.txt
├── 10.banana.txt
├── 101.orange.txt
```

Maybe `awk` or a regular expressions can accomplish this task, but I don’t know how to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a simple shell-loop, which you can enter at the command-prompt as a "one-liner":

```bash
for d in */; do n="${d%/}".txt; mv "${d}foo.txt" "$n"; rmdir "$d"; done
```

This will iterate over all subdirectories (i.e. items in the current directory that match the pattern `*/`), and

- generate a new filename by appending `.txt` to the directory name `$d` where the trailing `/` is removed in the process (`${d%/}`)
- moves the file inside the directory to the current directory using the new name `$n`, and
- removes the now-empty directory `$d` in the end.

*To err on the safe side*, try it first as follows:

```bash
for d in */; do n="${d%/}".txt; echo "mv ${d}foo.txt $n; rmdir $d"; done
```

This will only *print* the commands that the loop would otherwise execute, so you have the possibility to revise in case of typos or otherwise unexpected behavior.

Comment: @XueSongYe You're welcome, glad I could help. You may know this already, but in case you are interested in "further reading", [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is a good resource on shell programming.